# How to add onchange event on ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var val = "Hi";
        $.ajax ({
            url: "1.php?id",
            data: { id : val }

        });
    });
});
</script>

<form name="numbers" id="numbers">
    <input type="text" name="id" id="btn">
<input type="text">
</form>
```

This code is for click event but i want onchange event like on select option. Can anybody suggest me how to add onchange event on this ajax code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Search here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: Where is `select` and `option`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").on("change", function() {
        var val = "Hi";
        $.ajax ({
            url: "1.php?id",
            data: { id : val }

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="btn" onchange="ajaxfunction()" />

<script>
function ajaxfunction()
{
    enter ajax code here
}
</script>
```

Comment: Always try to add a brief explanation of what you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using keyup like so.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").keyup(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "1.php?id",
            data: { id: val }

        });
    });
});
```